# What size replacement screw to get for a Rosslaire Security Keypad?

Tags: screws, security

I have a Rosslaire Security Keypad ([AC-Q41HB Anti-Vandal Backlit PIN Standalone Controller](https://www.southwestautomated.com/product/anti-vandal-backlit-pin-standalone-controller/)) for my side door. The screw the holds that holds the keypad tight on the back panel got lost (the small screw on the bottom). What are the dimensions for the replacement screw?

Comment: Security spline or security hex screw? Contact the mfr. But in the meantime, try 8-32, 6-32 and be prepared to cut them short.

Comment: I don't know what those are @AloysiusDefenestrate

Comment: Those are machine screw sizes; you'll find them in the electrical aisle of your local big or small hardware store. Now that I think about it, there's also the possibility that they are metric -- I'd expect M2 or M3, which might be a little harder to find. (Ask store staff.)

Comment: Contacting the manufacturer is probably the easiest.  Those small screws can almost be a guessing game if the screw fits right or is almost close enough, but wrong.  Add in standard and metric to the mix, and you end up needing a handful of different sizes.

Comment: If there is another screw on the device that isn't lost and fits into the currently empty hole, you can take it to your local hardware store where they'll likely be able to help you find a matching replacement.